# Comparing first letters in c#.net

Tags: c#

I want to compare _code with the **first 3 letters** of AUS-BIS-000129(AUS), IF both are same then will continue with the if condition. How can I do that?

The value of  _Code will be 3 Letters for example(AUS,AUA,AUB). 
So if (AUS="AUS-BIS-000129") then I have to do some query.AUS-BIS-000129 is a string

```
 If (_code = AUS-BIS-000129)
     {
     }
```

Comment: If ``AUS-BIS-000129`` is a string, please read about comparing string, matching beginnings/ends/substrings etc. Otherwise, please specify what exactly it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it:

```
if("AUS-BIS-000129".StartsWith(_code))
{
  //...
}
```